# Filtering data based on boolean columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, filtering

I have the following pandas dataframe and I would like a function that returns the ID's data with at least 1 True value in `bool_1`, 2 True values in `bool_2` and 3 True values in `bool_3` column, using the `groupby` function.

```
index  ID  bool_1  bool_2  bool_3
 0      7   True    True    True    
 1      7   False   True    True
 2      7   False   False   True
 3      8   True    True    True
 4      8   True    True    True    
 5      8   False   False   True    
 6      9   True    True    True    
 7      9   True    False   True    
 8      9   True    False   True    
 9      9   True    False   False
```

As output I would expect complete data for `ID` `7` and `8` to be returned, since `9` has only 1 True value for `bool_2`.
Any idea for that function? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify number of `True`s in dictionary, so possible compare by [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) for greate or equal count of `True`s by aggregate sum and filter original `DataFrame` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
d = {'bool_1':1, 'bool_2':2,'bool_3':3}

ids = df.groupby('ID')[list(d.keys())].sum().ge(d).all(axis=1)
print (ids)
ID
7     True
8     True
9    False
dtype: bool

out = df[df['ID'].isin(ids.index[ids])]
print (out)
   index  ID  bool_1  bool_2  bool_3
0      0   7    True    True    True
1      1   7   False    True    True
2      2   7   False   False    True
3      3   8    True    True    True
4      4   8    True    True    True
5      5   8   False   False    True
```

Another idea is use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for create boolean mask:

```
d = {'bool_1':1, 'bool_2':2,'bool_3':3}

mask = df.groupby('ID')[list(d.keys())].transform('sum').ge(d).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

out = df[mask]
print (out)
   index  ID  bool_1  bool_2  bool_3
0      0   7    True    True    True
1      1   7   False    True    True
2      2   7   False   False    True
3      3   8    True    True    True
4      4   8    True    True    True
5      5   8   False   False    True
```

Comment: How would you answer change if the value of interest was the False instead of the True ? Same question but counting the Falses instead of Trues. Thank you.

Comment: @Telis - You ca change first part of answer by invert mask `ids = (~df[list(d.keys())]).groupby(df['ID']).sum().ge(d).all(axis=1)` - it workign same like `df[list(d.keys())].eq(False).groupby(df['ID']).sum().ge(d).all(axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

The following function might work:

```
def filter_dataframe(df):
    # Group by ID and calculate the sum of True values in each column
    grouped_df = df.groupby('ID').agg({
        'bool_1': 'sum',
        'bool_2': 'sum',
        'bool_3': 'sum'
    })

    # Filter rows based on the conditions
    filtered_df = grouped_df[(grouped_df['bool_1'] >= 1) & (grouped_df['bool_2'] >= 2) & (grouped_df['bool_3'] >= 3)]

    # Get the corresponding IDs
    selected_ids = filtered_df.index

    # Filter the original dataframe based on the selected IDs
    result_df = df[df['ID'].isin(selected_ids)]

    return result_df
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple groupby with sum aggregation function, then you can use any filtering method you like.

A very shorter way to achieve that is:

```
df.groupby('ID')[['bool_1', 'bool_2', 'bool_3']].sum().query('bool_1>0 & bool_2>1 & bool_3>2')
```

Which will give you:

```
ID | bool_1 | bool_2 | bool_3
7  |   1    |   2    |   3
8  |   2    |   2    |   3
```